# How do I get more control of UIImageView animation?

Tags: iphone

I'm trying to display a series of images in a animation where the duration between the images changes frame to frame.  I can successfully animate images where the duration is the same.  I've looked into subclassing UIImageView but it doesn't seem to allow you access anything that could be helpful.

I've also looked into subclassing UIView directly but it seems like I'd have to write a lot of the stuff that UIImageView already does for me.

Is there a way to do this with UIImageView?  Or if I am going to have to build my own UIView animation can someone point me the right direction to get started?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could have many UIImageViews next to one another, each representing one image, and animate them inside a UIView or UIScrollView, depending on what exactly you need to do. Animations with the help of UIView are very straightforward to implement.